# Aligning strings in Python

Tags: python

I searched for creating aligned strings in Python and found some relevant stuff, but didn't work for me. Here's one example:

```
for line in [[1, 128, 1298039], [123388, 0, 2]]:
    print('{:>8} {:>8} {:>8}'.format(*line))
```

Output:

```
       1      128  1298039
  123388        0        2
```

This is what I see in the shell:

[image: Shell screenshot]

As you can see, the alignment didn't happen. Same problem arises when using `\t`.
What can I do to align the strings in a neat, tabular format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have configured your IDLE shell to use a *proportional* font, one that uses different widths for different characters. Notice how the `()` pair takes almost the same amount of horizontal space as the `>` character above it.

Your code is otherwise entirely correct; with a fixed-width font the numbers *will* line up correctly.

Switch to using a *fixed width* font instead. Courier is a good default choice, but Windows has various other fonts installed that are proportional, including Consolas.

Configure the font in the *Options -> Configure IDLE* menu. Pick a different font from the Font Face list. The sample characters in the panel below should line up (except for the second line `k` at the end, it should stick out).

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPeters. Are there other fixed width fonts available?

Comment: @SamChats: plenty. They are also called "monospaced", search on google for some more. Off the top of my head: Lucida Sans Typewriter, Monaco, Andale Mono, Menlo, Courier, Courier New, PT Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, etc. etc.