# how to merge or join lists and match records in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I did search and could not find anything close enough.

Consider these 3 or more lists containing files names or any other object - a list found in say specific directories(relevant):

```
list1 = ['c:\\temp\\file1.txt', 'c:\\temp\\file2.txt', 'c:\\temp\\file3.txt']
list2 = ['d:\\myfiles\\file1.txt', 'd:\\myfiles\\file2.tx', 'd:\\myfiles\\file4.txt']
list3 = ['d:\\backup\\file2.txt', 'd:\\backup\\file3.txt', 'd:\\backup\\file4.txt']
```

What I want to obtain is a table with three columns (could be excel, pipe-delimited txt or similar) with three columns:

```
column1 (c:\\temp) | column2 (d:\\myfiles) | column3 (d:\\backup)
------------------------------------------------------------------
file1.txt          | file1.txt             | <blank>
file2.txt          | file2.txt             | file2.txt
file3.txt          | <blank>               | file3.txt
<blank>            | file4.txt             | file4.txt
```

I have the list but I'm unaware of a function or method that would sort the list in the fashion provided above. Python 2.7 - is what I'm using.

Any ideas welcome.

-geo

Comment: Are the lists sorted by filenames?

Comment: that's quite some code you're asking to write...

Comment: Please pay attention to the "Related" links to previous answers on the right - they all have upvotes in 4-digit range (rarely see that). One of them just has to work...

Comment: No - i was not asking to provide the code (maybe I did not make it clear :( ) - merely ideas of structures that can be used. I'm mentally stuck on using lists, but as others suggested perhaps a dictionary might be better. I can actually do this by putting all the items together (sorting, grabbing the largest list, and then appending/concatenating if the value is found and moving on....but it might require an iteration per list  but it just does not seem elegant enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Sam in that the first step is to transform your lists into a dictionary of lists.

```
from collections import defaultdict

flattened_list = [s for sub in [list1, list2, list3] for s in sub]
tracker = defaultdict(list)

for path in flattened_list:
    dirname, _, basename = path.rpartition('\\')
    tracker[dirname].append(basename)

# {'c:\\temp':    ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt'], 
#  'd:\\myfiles': ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file4.txt'], 
#  'd:\\backup':  ['file2.txt', 'file3.txt', 'file4.txt']}
```

From here, converting this data into either a list of column data or a list of row data is straight forward.

```
dirnames = sorted(tracker)
basenames = sorted(set(sum(tracker.values(), []))) # a set of all file names

# constructs a list for each directory, filling in empty slots with '<blank>'
files = [[b if b in tracker[d] else '<blank>' for b in basenames] for d in dirnames]

column_output = [[d] + f for d, f in zip(dirnames, files)]
# [['c:\\temp',    'file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt', '<blank>'], 
#  ['d:\\myfiles', 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt', '<blank>',   'file4.txt'],
#  ['d:\\backup',  '<blank>',   'file2.txt', 'file3.txt', 'file4.txt']]

row_output = zip(*column_output)
# [('c:\\temp',  'd:\\backup', 'd:\\myfiles'), 
#  ('file1.txt', '<blank>',    'file1.txt'), 
#  ('file2.txt', 'file2.txt',  'file2.txt'), 
#  ('file3.txt', 'file3.txt',  '<blank>'), 
#  ('<blank>',   'file4.txt',  'file4.txt')]
```

Printing these or writing them to an Excel file in the way you want is another question, but should be easy enough.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was stuck on....for some reason I kept thinking in the 'list' mode. The dictionary is the right structure; and you are right the export to excel or text is easy - I already have a routine to do  just that. Regards! Thank you all : )

Answer (score 1):

Won't a dictionary be a better data structure for the problem you're working on? First, let's convert your data into a dictionary:

```
collections = [list1, list2, list3]
files = {'\\'.join(collection[0].split('\\')[:-1]): [item.split('\\')[-1] for item in collection] for collection in collections}
```

I know that's a big hairy comprehension, but it'll give you a nice dictionary:

```
{'c:\\temp': ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt'], 'd:\\myfiles': ['file1.txt', 'file2.tx', 'file4.txt'], 'd:\\backup': ['file2.txt', 'file3.txt', 'file4.txt']}
```

Now, to display the files in a manner you desire, we can simply loop over the keys, and then values of the dictionary:

```
# Headers
for key in files.keys():
    print("%-15s" % key, end="")
print("\n" + "="*44)

#Values
size = max(len(val) for val in files.values())
for i in range(size):
    for path in files:
        name =  "file%s.txt" % str(i+1)
        if name in files[path]:
           print("%-15s" % name, end="")
        else:
            print("%-15s" % "<blank>", end="")
    print()
```

Output is as desired:

```
c:\temp        d:\myfiles     d:\backup
============================================
file1.txt      file1.txt      <blank>        
file2.txt      <blank>        file2.txt      
file3.txt      <blank>        file3.txt
```

Note: [This may only work for monospaced fonts.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417888/aligning-strings-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for all the ideas. Just I'm actually only stuck in the 'sorting part'. I also am working on something that is not just filex, but the filename is definitely constant -if it exists.  i will go back to the related questions (thanks logan) for the suggestion.

Comment: @GeoDerthal Alright. Did you try running my code? Is it working?

Comment: Not yet. Thank you for your solution; I think with some variations I might be able to get something to work soon.